# Database Learning Curve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, database-design

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) question contains complete learning curve for Cpp from **Beginner**,**Intermediate** and **advance** which is very helpful.

Please suggest me same for Databases,to become a good **Database Expert** or a **Good DBA**. As there are may books and tutorials which to choose.

Comment: off-topic, the question is opinion-based

Comment: @simon The thing is that I am just a starter and I was the Question which is mentioned in the thread and asked. Please share your opinion,it would be good for me.

Comment: @nitesh.kodle123 - did you see the note on that question: *"This question has historical significance, but is not a good example of an appropriate question. Read and learn from this post, but please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following books written by Itzik Ben-Gan very helpful:

*Beginning:*

1. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals
   [http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-2012-T-SQL-Fundamentals/dp/0735658145](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658145)

*Advanced:*

1. Training Kit (Exam 70-461): Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012
   (MSPress, December 2012)
   [http://www.amazon.com/Training-Kit-Exam-70-461-Microsoft/dp/0735666059](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735666059)
2. Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming (MSPress, 2009) 
   [http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-Server%C2%AE-2008-Pro-Developer/dp/0735626022/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1ZFP1YGEB2QPZBZCBFZS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626022)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: learn the internals

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2012-Internals/dp/0735658560](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658560)

From there you have a solid knowledge of querytuning, how the optmizer works and solid knowledge of how SQl Server works. Something every dba should know.

And the books of Iztik Ben Gan:
[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server%C2%AE-2008/dp/0735626030/ref=sr_1_sc_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1393572731&sr=1-2-spell&keywords=iztik+ben+gan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626030)